# Парсинг названия видео из YouTube

Tags: python, парсер

Всем добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно спарсить название видео на ютубе? К примеру хочу взять название из этой трансляции: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03xw2mr0Zb8

**Виктория-Победительница | Полные эпизоды | Nick Rewind Россия**

Как с помощью **Python** подобраться к h1? Что означает **yt-formatted-string**? Заранее большое спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с помощью BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03xw2mr0Zb8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
tmp = soup.find('span', class_='watch-title metadata-updateable-title')
print(tmp.text)
```

Вывод:

```
Виктория-Победительница | Полные эпизоды | Nick Rewind Россия
```

Вы с разных мест можете достать нужную вам информацию, вот например еще:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r  = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03xw2mr0Zb8")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
tmp = soup.find('h1', class_='watch-title-container')


print(tmp.text)
```

Вывод:

```
Виктория-Победительница | Полные эпизоды | Nick Rewind Россия
```

Ваш суп (его малая часть) выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть можно просто было ввести спан и не париться, спасибо!

Comment: Извините, а откуда Вы взяли watch-title metadata-updateable-title? Его просто нет вообще

Comment: по созданию `soup` я его распечатал и нашел `<span class="watch-title metadata-updateable-title" dir="ltr" id="eow-title" title="Виктория-Победительница | Полные эпизоды | Nick Rewind Россия">
    Виктория-Победительница | Полные эпизоды | Nick Rewind Россия
  </span>` а потом как в коде выше

Comment: Извините, я просто не вижу где находится этот спан, в упор не вижу `<span class="watch-title metadata-updateable-title" dir="ltr" id="eow-title" title="Виктория-Победительница | Полные эпизоды | Nick Rewind Россия"> Виктория-Победительница | Полные эпизоды | Nick Rewind Россия </span>`

Comment: вижу `<h1 class="title style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer">` а в нем `<yt-formatted-string force-default-style class="style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer">Виктория-Победительница | Полные эпизоды | Nick Rewind Россия</yt-formatted-string>`

Comment: в ответе в конце добавил как выглядит суп

Comment: я понял, очень Вам благодарен!!!

Comment: на самом деле вы создаете суп и потом `ctrl+Shift+C` и выделяете то, что вас интересует и видите необходимые теги. Но почему-то( не знаю почему, сам новичок в парсинге) когда я вставляю те теги с окна разработчика, мне выдает пустой список. Выглядит так, что суп как-то иначе прочитывает страницу. Для этого я распечатал его, и уже там выискал нужные теги. Когда я парсил другие сайты, то сразу срабатывали теги со страницы разработки. Может кто-то еще выяснит это :)

Comment: Вот иногда без принта супа срабатывает, но теперь благодаря Вам узнал, что можно писать суп и в нём тоже искать. Спасибо!

Comment: почитал, мы выбрали в супе библиотеку `html.parser ---> (BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser'))`. Есть еще в документации `html5lib`. В описание написано: `Parses pages the same way a web browser does`. Скорее всего в этом и проблема. Печатать за каждым разом суп неправильно, представьте что там +100500 строчек :)     https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers